# Operation not permitted while launch mr job

Tags: hadoop, kerberos, cloudera

I have change my kerberos cluster to unkerberized 
after that below Exception occurred while launching MR jobs.

Application application_1458558692044_0001 failed 1 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1458558692044_0001_000001 exited with exitCode: -1000
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://hdp1.impetus.co.in:8088/proxy/application_1458558692044_0001/Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: Operation not permitted
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to continue my work 
delete yarn folder from all the nodes which is define on **yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs** this property 
then restart yarn process